# Cascading deletion with Ado.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net, cascade, cascading-deletes

I have an application which i need to delete a row from the table `Client`

```
public void Delete_Client(int _id_client)
        {
            Data.Connect();
            using (Data.connexion)
            {
                string s = "Delete From CLIENT where id_client = " + _id_client;
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(s, Data.connexion);
                try
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
```

the table `Client` contains a foreign references to another table. So an exception appears indicates that the deletion must be cascade.

So how can i change my code to do this ( i'am using sql server as a dbms) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you should avoid using `on delete cascade` because:

1. You lose control what is being removed
2. Table references has to be altered to enable it
3. Use parametrized query (as all around advice)

So lets change your query. I added `ClientOrder` as example table which holds foreign key reference to our soon to be deleted client.
First of all I remove all orders linked to client, then I delete client itself. This should go like this for all the other tables
that are linked with `Client` table.

```cs
public void Delete_Client(int _id_client)
{
    Data.Connect();

    using (Data.connexion)
    {
        string query = "delete from ClientOrder where id_client = @clientId; delete From CLIENT where id_client = @clientid";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, Data.connexion);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientId", _id_client);

        try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch { } //silencing errors is wrong, if something goes wrong you should handle it 
    }
}
```

Parametrized query has many advantages. First of all it is safer (look at SQL Injection attack). Second types are resolved by framework (especially helpful for `DateTime` with formatting).